# Get current logged on Windows 7 user, PHP

Tags: php

The command that I want to use is: "wmic /node:(computer name) computersystem get username"

This command simply returns the current user that is logged on. I want this embedded into our intranet (PHP), so that users can know if a particular computer is in use. However, I need help. I know some PHP, but some pointers or suggestions on how to start would be helpful.

Any suggestions are welcome. Please and thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `system()`
This function executes a system command and gives you the result back.

```
string system( string $command [, int &$return_var ])
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php

In your case :

```
<?php
    echo "<pre>".system("wmic /node:(computer name) computersystem get username")."</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: if you like the answer accept it (left of the answer there is a grey "v")